# How does C handle the stack and is that what is causing this problem?

Tags: gcc, assembly, memory-management, x86, osdev

I have some code from a tutorial based on the James Molloy OS tutorial, and I'm trying to fix interrupts, but I have edited the code to use a pointer as an argument for the C handler (To fix a bug in the code). Now I am having a problem where after the C function is called and the `ds` register is set to an address popped off the stack (presumably 0x8), it cause QEMU to reboot. I think it might be due to some way that C uses the stack, so it might be that the value that is removed from the stack and the value `ds` is set to is garbage (Not 0x8).

I have done some testing with GDB and I figured out that the OS exits upon setting `ds` to the value loaded off the stack after the function call.

Here are the handlers:

```c
void isr_handler(registers_t *r) {
    kprint("received interrupt: ");
    char s[5];
    int_to_ascii(r->int_no, s);
    kprint(s);
    kprint("\n");
    kprint("error code: ");
    char e[3];
    int_to_ascii(r->err_code, s);
    kprint(s);
    kprint("\n");
    kprint(exception_messages[r->int_no]);
    kprint("\n");
}
void irq_handler(registers_t *r) {
    /* After every interrupt we need to send an EOI to the PICs
     * or they will not send another interrupt again */
    if (r->int_no >= 40) port_byte_out(0xA0, 0x20); /* slave */
    port_byte_out(0x20, 0x20); /* master */
    /* Handle the interrupt in a more modular way */
    if (interrupt_handlers[r->int_no] != 0) {
        isr_t handler = interrupt_handlers[r->int_no];
        handler(r);
    } 
    else {
        if (loaded == 1) {
            kprint("");
        }
    }
}
```

And the assembly code:

```
; Common ISR code
isr_common_stub:
    ; 1. Save CPU state
    pushad ; Pushes edi,esi,ebp,esp,ebx,edx,ecx,eax
    mov ax, ds ; Lower 16-bits of eax = ds.
    push eax ; save the data segment descriptor
    mov ax, 0x10  ; kernel data segment descriptor
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    push esp

    ; 2. Call C handler
    call isr_handler
    pop eax

    ; 3. Restore state
    pop eax 
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    popad
    add esp, 8 ; Cleans up the pushed error code and pushed ISR number
    sti
    iret ; pops 5 things at once: CS, EIP, EFLAGS, SS, and ESP

; Common IRQ code. Identical to ISR code except for the 'call' 
; and the 'pop ebx'
irq_common_stub:
    pushad
    mov ax, ds
    push eax
    mov ax, 0x10 ;0x10
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    push esp                 ; At this point ESP is a pointer to where DS (and the rest
                             ; of the interrupt handler state resides)
                             ; Push ESP as 1st parameter as it's a 
                             ; pointer to a registers_t  
    call irq_handler
    pop ebx                  ; Remove the saved ESP on the stack. Efficient to just pop it 
                             ; into any register. You could have done: add esp, 4 as well
    pop ebx
    mov ds, bx
    mov es, bx
    mov fs, bx
    mov gs, bx
    popad
    add esp, 8
    sti
    iret
```

And the handler which causes a problem:

```c
static void keyboard_callback(registers_t *regs) {
    /* The PIC leaves us the scancode in port 0x60 */
    uint8_t scancode = port_byte_in(0x60);
    bool iskeyup = false;
    if (scancode >= KEYUPOFFSET) {
        iskeyup = true;
        scancode -= KEYUPOFFSET;
    }
    key_handler(scancode, iskeyup);
    UNUSED(regs);
}
```

Memory code that gets called from the problematic command

```c
if (strcmp(input, "testMemLess") == 0) {
        uint32_t pAddr;
        uint32_t *test1 = kmalloc(0x1000);
        uint32_t *test2 = kmalloc(0x1000);
        *test2 = 255;
        *test1 = 256;
        sprintd("Data test:");
        sprint_uint(*test1);
        sprint("\n");
        sprintd("Test 2:");
        sprint_uint(*test2);
        char temp[25];
        int_to_ascii(memoryRemaining, temp);
        sprint("\nMemory Remaining: ");
        sprint(temp);
        sprint(" bytes\n");
        free(test1, 0x1000);
        free(test2, 0x1000);
        sprintd("EXECUTION COMPLETE");
    }
```

Free and kmalloc:

```c
/* Recursive function to find the best fitting block of mem to use */
void * bestFit(uint32_t size, uint32_t curFit, uint32_t curAddr, uint32_t curFitBlock) {
    uint32_t *nextFreeBlock = get_pointer(curAddr);
    uint32_t *freeSize = get_pointer(curAddr+4);
    uint32_t fit = curFit;
    uint32_t block = curFitBlock;
    uint32_t s = size;
    if (*nextFreeBlock != 0 && *freeSize != 0 && *nextFreeBlock >= MIN && *nextFreeBlock + s <= MAX) {
        /* There is actually memory here */
        uint32_t data = 180; // Random test value
        uint32_t *ptr = get_pointer(*nextFreeBlock+8);
        *ptr = data;
        uint32_t inputD = *ptr;
        if (inputD == data) {
            /* Cool, the memory works */
            if (size <= *freeSize) {
                uint32_t dif = abs(*freeSize-size);
                if (dif < curFit) {
                    fit = dif;
                    block = *nextFreeBlock;
                }
            }
            return bestFit(s, fit, *nextFreeBlock, block);
        } else
        {
            return get_pointer(curFitBlock);
        }

    } else
    {
        return get_pointer(curFitBlock);
    }

}

void block_move(blockData_t *d) {
    // Current is the current free block to read from, equal to addr
    // Size is the size of the current block
    // pAddr is the address to pass to the next call
    // pSize is the size to pass to the next call
    uint32_t current = d->chain_next;
    uint32_t *current_ptr = get_pointer(current);
    uint32_t *current_ptr_offset = get_pointer(current+4);
    uint32_t usedMemBlock = d->usedBlock;
    uint32_t usedBlockSize = d->usedBlockSize;

    if (*current_ptr != 0 && *current_ptr_offset != 0 && *current_ptr >= MIN && (*current_ptr + *current_ptr_offset) <= MAX) {
        // New pointer exists
        d->chain_next = *current_ptr;
        d->next_block_size = *current_ptr_offset;
        // After setting the values for the next call, handle this one
        if (*current_ptr == usedMemBlock) {
            // The next block is the block that is about to be used
            uint32_t *used_ptr = get_pointer(usedMemBlock);
            uint32_t *used_ptr_offset = get_pointer(usedMemBlock + 4);
            uint32_t used_pointing = *used_ptr;
            uint32_t used_pointing_size = *used_ptr_offset;
            *current_ptr = used_pointing;
            *current_ptr_offset = used_pointing_size;
            return;
        } else
        {
            return block_move(d);
        }

    } else {
        return;
    }
}

/* Implementation is just an address which
 * keeps growing, and a chunk scanner to find free chunks. */
uint32_t kmalloc_int(uint32_t size, int align) {
    /* Pages are aligned to 4K, or 0x1000 */
    if (align == 1 && (free_mem_addr & 0xFFFFF000)) {
        free_mem_addr &= 0xFFFFF000;
        free_mem_addr += 0x1000;
    }
    /* Save also the physical address */
    void * bFit = bestFit(size, MAX - free_mem_addr, free_mem_addr, free_mem_addr);
    uint32_t ret = bFit;;
    blockData_t *param;
    uint32_t *f1 = get_pointer(free_mem_addr);
    uint32_t *f2 = get_pointer(free_mem_addr+4);
    param->chain_next = f1;
    param->next_block_size = f2;
    param->usedBlock = ret;
    param->usedBlockSize = size;
    block_move(param);
    if (ret == free_mem_addr) {
        free_mem_addr += size; /* Remember to increment the pointer */
    }
    memoryRemaining -= size;
    usedMem += size;
    return ret;
}

void * kmalloc(uint32_t size) {
    void * t = get_pointer(kmalloc_int(size, 0));
    return t;
}

void free(void * addr, uint32_t size) {
    void *address = get_pointer(addr);
    uint32_t *free_ptr = get_pointer(free_mem_addr);
    uint32_t *free_ptr_offset = get_pointer(free_mem_addr + 4);
    uint32_t curAddr = *free_ptr;
    uint32_t curSize = *free_ptr_offset;
    uint32_t *addr_base = get_pointer(address);
    uint32_t *addr_size = get_pointer(address+4);

    if (address + size == free_mem_addr) {
        /* Add new block to the chain */
        memory_set(address, 0, size);
        uint32_t lastAddr = *free_ptr;
        uint32_t lastSize = *free_ptr_offset;
        free_mem_addr -= size;
        free_ptr = get_pointer(free_mem_addr);
        free_ptr_offset = get_pointer(free_mem_addr + 4);
        *free_ptr = lastAddr;
        *free_ptr_offset = lastSize;
    } else {
        memory_set(address, 0, size);
        *addr_base = curAddr;
        *addr_size = curSize;
        *free_ptr = address;
        *free_ptr_offset = size;
    }


    memoryRemaining += size;
    usedMem -= size;

    sprint("\n\n\n");
}
```

Also, the GitHub repo if you want to run it: https://github.com/Menotdan/DripOS/tree/dev

EDIT: The problem only happens when I call a command that is for testing memory, and no, the memory test does not overwrite stack memory. See memory code above.

EDIT 2: I have done some debugging and I figured out that `ds` gets set to 0, so it is popping the incorrect value of the stack.

---

The code uses a version of `kmalloc` and `free` that I have developed. The start of the heap space is passed into my `kmain` function and used by `kmalloc`. My `boot.s` file looks like:

```
/* Enable intel syntax */
.intel_syntax noprefix
/* Declare constants for the multiboot header. */
.set ALIGN,    1<<0             /* align loaded modules on page boundaries */
.set MEMINFO,  1<<1             /* provide memory map */
.set FLAGS,    ALIGN | MEMINFO  /* this is the Multiboot 'flag' field */
.set MAGIC,    0x1BADB002       /* 'magic number' lets bootloader find the header */
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS) /* checksum of above, to prove we are multiboot */

/*
Declare a multiboot header that marks the program as a kernel. These are magic
values that are documented in the multiboot standard. The bootloader will
search for this signature in the first 8 KiB of the kernel file, aligned at a
32-bit boundary. The signature is in its own section so the header can be
forced to be within the first 8 KiB of the kernel file.
*/
.section .multiboot
.align 4
.long MAGIC
.long FLAGS
.long CHECKSUM

.section .data
/*
GDT from the old DripOS bootloader, which was from the original
project (The OS tutorial)
*/

gdt_start:

        .long 0x0
        .long 0x0

gdt_code:
        .word 0xffff
        .word 0x0
        .byte 0x0
        .byte 0x9A /*10011010 in binary*/
        .byte 0xCF /*11001111 in binary*/
        .byte 0x0
gdt_data:
        .word 0xffff
        .word 0x0
        .byte 0x0
        .byte 0x92 /*10010010 in binary*/
        .byte 0xCF /*11001111 in binary*/
        .byte 0x0

gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
        .word gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
        .long gdt_start

CODE_SEG = gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG = gdt_data - gdt_start

/*
The multiboot standard does not define the value of the stack pointer register
(esp) and it is up to the kernel to provide a stack. This allocates room for a
small stack by creating a symbol at the bottom of it, then allocating 16384
bytes for it, and finally creating a symbol at the top. The stack grows
downwards on x86. The stack is in its own section so it can be marked nobits,
which means the kernel file is smaller because it does not contain an
uninitialized stack. The stack on x86 must be 16-byte aligned according to the
System V ABI standard and de-facto extensions. The compiler will assume the
stack is properly aligned and failure to align the stack will result in
undefined behavior.
*/
.section .bss
.align 16
stack_bottom:
.skip 16384 # 16 KiB
stack_top:

/*
The linker script specifies _start as the entry point to the kernel and the
bootloader will jump to this position once the kernel has been loaded. It
doesn't make sense to return from this function as the bootloader is gone.
*/
.section .text
.global _start
.type _start, @function
_start:
        /*
        The bootloader has loaded us into 32-bit protected mode on a x86
        machine. Interrupts are disabled. Paging is disabled. The processor
        state is as defined in the multiboot standard. The kernel has full
        control of the CPU. The kernel can only make use of hardware features
        and any code it provides as part of itself. There's no printf
        function, unless the kernel provides its own <stdio.h> header and a
        printf implementation. There are no security restrictions, no
        safeguards, no debugging mechanisms, only what the kernel provides
        itself. It has absolute and complete power over the
        machine.
        */

        /*
        To set up a stack, we set the esp register to point to the top of the
        stack (as it grows downwards on x86 systems). This is necessarily done
        in assembly as languages such as C cannot function without a stack.
        */
        mov stack_top, esp

        /*
        This is a good place to initialize crucial processor state before the
        high-level kernel is entered. It's best to minimize the early
        environment where crucial features are offline. Note that the
        processor is not fully initialized yet: Features such as floating
        point instructions and instruction set extensions are not initialized
        yet. The GDT should be loaded here. Paging should be enabled here.
        C++ features such as global constructors and exceptions will require
        runtime support to work as well.
        */
        lgdt [gdt_descriptor] /* Load the GDT */
        /*
        Enter the high-level kernel. The ABI requires the stack is 16-byte
        aligned at the time of the call instruction (which afterwards pushes
        the return pointer of size 4 bytes). The stack was originally 16-byte
        aligned above and we've since pushed a multiple of 16 bytes to the
        stack since (pushed 0 bytes so far) and the alignment is thus
        preserved and the call is well defined.
        */
        /* Credit goes to Michael Petch on StackOverflow for helping correctly write this*/
    mov ax, DATA_SEG
        mov ds, ax
        mov es, ax
        mov fs, ax
        mov gs, ax
    jmp CODE_SEG:.next /* JMP to next instruction but set CS! */
.next:
        .att_syntax
        push $test
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        push ebx
        /*mov ebp, 0x90000
        mov esp, ebp*/
        call kmain

        /*
        If the system has nothing more to do, put the computer into an
        infinite loop. To do that:
        1) Disable interrupts with cli (clear interrupt enable in eflags).
           They are already disabled by the bootloader, so this is not needed.
           Mind that you might later enable interrupts and return from
           kernel_main (which is sort of nonsensical to do).
        2) Wait for the next interrupt to arrive with hlt (halt instruction).
           Since they are disabled, this will lock up the computer.
        3) Jump to the hlt instruction if it ever wakes up due to a
           non-maskable interrupt occurring or due to system management mode.
        */
        cli
1:      hlt
        jmp 1b

/*
Set the size of the _start symbol to the current location '.' minus its start.
This is useful when debugging or when you implement call tracing.
*/
.size _start, . - _start
test:
```

I use this as a linker script:

```
/* The bootloader will look at this image and start execution at the symbol
   designated as the entry point. */
ENTRY(_start)

/* Tell where the various sections of the object files will be put in the final
   kernel image. */
SECTIONS
{
    /* Begin putting sections at 1 MiB, a conventional place for kernels to be
       loaded at by the bootloader. */
    . = 1M;

    /* First put the multiboot header, as it is required to be put very early
       early in the image or the bootloader won't recognize the file format.
       Next we'll put the .text section. */
    .text BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.multiboot)
        *(.text)
    }

    /* Read-only data. */
    .rodata BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }

    /* Read-write data (initialized) */
    .data BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.data)
    }

    /* Read-write data (uninitialized) and stack */
    .bss BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
    }

    /* The compiler may produce other sections, by default it will put them in
       a segment with the same name. Simply add stuff here as needed. */
}
```

Comment: This may or may not be relevant - are you sure `s` in `isr_handler` is big enough to store a string representation of all possible values of `int_no` or `err_code`?  IOW, will those values always be between `0` and `99`?

Comment: @JohnBode That is not relevant, but it something that might cause problems. The reason it is not relevant is that ```keyboard_callback``` (The interrupt supposedly causing the problem) is an IRQ, not an ISR

Comment: OT: "I expect the code to work without any problems, but ..." Welcome to the world of programming... :-)

Comment: @4386427 Yep I didn't really know what to put there. I am probably going to remove it.

Comment: Notice that the use of a stack is not something required/described by the C standard. A stack is an implementation thing. For a specific implementation (aka system), you can find an ABI document that describes how it's done. (ABI == Application binary interface)

Comment: @4386427 (1)
Also, I found the System V ABI document for Intel386

Comment: It may not be related to the issue, but the STI before IRET looks dubious to me: afaik, the flags popped by IRET should override it anyway.

Comment: @ChrisSmeele Yeah ive had that mentioned to me before I will change it later

Comment: You need to use a debugger to investigate problems like this. Although @ChrisSmeele is right about the STI that is unneeded, it isn't the problem. Does your code work if you remove the calls to `free` at the bottom of the `testMemLess` code? I suspect that `free` is screwing up and has obliterated part of the data on the stack causing a value of 0 to be popped off for EAX and then 0 (in EAX) is loaded into DS (in the IRQ assembly code) and that it fails there. The other possibility is `free`wiped out the GDT in memory lol

Comment: In fact wiping out the GDT is as likely a scenario with a bad `free`. Overwriting the GDT would almost likely cause the next load of any segment register to fail. Your free seems to zero out the memory it is freeing as well making such a scenario likely.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Hmm maybe, but I have a label at the end of code in ```boot.s``` that has its address passed to kmain, and then the code uses the address to do some math to find out where the free memory pointer should be, because earlier I ran into a problem where ```kmalloc``` would overwrite itself and QEMU would crash

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yeah it does seem like removing free fixes the problem.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Huh, interesting. How would I make sure the GDT was behind the label that I mentioned?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199542/discussion-between-menotdan-and-michael-petch).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem isn't really about IRQ handling. Your `kmalloc` and `free` routines are based on the assumption that in `boot.s` that you properly passed the address of the end of the kernel to `kmain`:

```
.att_syntax
push $test
.intel_syntax noprefix
push ebx
call kmain
```

The problem is that you define `test` in `boot.s` as:

```
.section .text

[snipped the code for brevity]

.size _start, . - _start
test:
```

Your label `test` is not at the end of your kernel. It happens to simply be set at the end of the code in `boot.s` . Your linker script arranges the `.text` section so it appears before `.data`:

```
/* Read-write data (initialized) */
.data BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
{
    *(.data)
}

/* Read-write data (uninitialized) and stack */
.bss BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
{
    *(COMMON)
    *(.bss)
}
```

The `test` label will have been placed somewhere in the `.text` section before the `.data` and `.bss`. The GDT happens to reside in the `.data` section. Your `kmalloc` has been told to use the `.data`, `.bss`, and any memory after it for heap space. The result is that your `free` has likely wiped out the GDT and then when it reached a point of doing `mov %eax, %ds` in `irq_common_stub`, the selector being loaded pointed to a corrupt GDT descriptor and thus faulted.

To fix the problem, remove the label `test` and create a symbol like `__kernel_end` in the linker script like this:

```
/* The bootloader will look at this image and start execution at the symbol
   designated as the entry point. */
ENTRY(_start)

/* Tell where the various sections of the object files will be put in the final
   kernel image. */
SECTIONS
{
        /* Begin putting sections at 1 MiB, a conventional place for kernels to be
           loaded at by the bootloader. */
        . = 1M;

        /* First put the multiboot header, as it is required to be put very early
           early in the image or the bootloader won't recognize the file format.
           Next we'll put the .text section. */
        .text BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
        {
                *(.multiboot)
                *(.text)
        }

        /* Read-only data. */
        .rodata BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
        {
                *(.rodata)
        }

        /* Read-write data (initialized) */
        .data BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
        {
                *(.data)
        }

        /* Read-write data (uninitialized) and stack */
        .bss BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
        {
                *(COMMON)
                *(.bss)
        }
        __kernel_end = .;

        /* The compiler may produce other sections, by default it will put them in
           a segment with the same name. Simply add stuff here as needed. */
}
```

In `boot.s` replace `push $test` with `push $__kernel_end`

---

Note: if you want `__kernel_end` (and thus the beginning of the heap space) to start on a 4KB aligned boundary after your kernel you could use this in the linker script instead:

```
__kernel_end = ALIGN(4K);
```

`ALIGN(4K)` will take the current location counter and align it up to the next 4KiB boundary and assign that address to the symbol `__kernel_end`.

---

### Observations

It is unclear why in this code you switched back to AT&T syntax and then back to Intel:

```
.next:
        .att_syntax
        push $__kernel_end
        .intel_syntax noprefix
```

This could have been written as:

```
.next:
        push __kernel_end
```